# java.lang.NumberFormatException Error shows when trying to run program

Tags: java, error-handling

This program is supposed to chop up and add together social security numbers. I thought I wrote all of the code correctly, but when I ran the code it outputted the *java.lang.NumberFormatException* error. I am using Eclipse and it doesn't show which line of the code has the error so I don't know what to fix. *Here are the two classes of code I am working with:*

MAIN CLASS:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class social
{
   private String socialNum;
   private int sum;

    public social()
    {
        setWord("");
    }

    public social(String soc)
    {
        setWord(soc);
    }


    public void setWord(String w)
    {
        socialNum = w;
    }

    public void chopAndAdd()
    {
        String sub1 = socialNum.substring(0, socialNum.indexOf("-"));
        String sub2 = socialNum.substring(socialNum.indexOf("-") + 1, socialNum.lastIndexOf("-"));
        String sub3 = socialNum.substring(socialNum.indexOf("-") + 1);

        int int1 = Integer.parseInt(sub1);
        int int2 = Integer.parseInt(sub2);
        int int3 = Integer.parseInt(sub3);

        sum = int1 + int2 + int3;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "SS# " + socialNum + " has a total of " + sum + "\n";
    }
}
```

RUNNER CLASS:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class socialrunner
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        //add test cases
        social test = new social("456-56-234");
        test.chopAndAdd();
        System.out.println(test);

        test.setWord("1-1-1");
        test.chopAndAdd();
        System.out.println(test);

        test.setWord("182-2-12");
        test.chopAndAdd();
        System.out.println(test);

        test.setWord("0-0-0");
        test.chopAndAdd();
        System.out.println(test);

    }
}
```

**Thanks for any help~!**

Comment: Have you tried debugging it to see when the exception is thrown?

Comment: no i haven't, I'll try to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is due to the line

```
String sub3 = socialNum.substring(socialNum.indexOf("-") + 1);
```

The code

```
socialNum.substring(socialNum.indexOf("-") + 1)
```

returns 56-234, which is not an Integer.  This causes the NumberFormatException when it tries parse this into an Int.
Change that line to,

```
String sub3 = socialNum.substring(socialNum.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
```

It will remove the error.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the error and outputs are correct~ : ^)

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
String sub3 = socialNum.substring(socialNum.indexOf("-") + 1);
```

makes the value of sub3 as "56-234" as the socialNum is "456-56-234".

Therefore Integer.parseInt method cannot parse a String with a "-" in it and thus throwing exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a NumberFormatException, you are trying to transform something that is not a number into a number.

Debug to see what you're getting on these lines:

```
int int1 = Integer.parseInt(sub1);
int int2 = Integer.parseInt(sub2);
int int3 = Integer.parseInt(sub3);
```